# Should we delete meta-tags?

Tags: discussion

Asked by @5chdn in a comment.  Should we delete meta-tags like [introducing-ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introducing-ethereum) ?
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags

Also, when a tag is deleted, is there a way of preventing the same term from being used to create the tag again?

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question, we have that issue with the recently disbanded tag smart-contracts. It has already alot of questions again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regarding [introducing-ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introducing-ethereum), if you have the resources/time, please remove or retag it. I don't see any reason why we should keep this.

Comment: Done, removed and retagged.